# Adding a prefix to the blog, but only the blog

Tags: permalinks

My client wants to add /news/ at the beginning of the url of his blogposts, but doing so, it adds /news/ to the start of all post types.

Even trying to use some 'custom permalink' plugins, the /news/ is forced to all urls. No matter the type.

Is there a way to add something to the URL of the blogs, but not to the URL of other post types?

Answer (score 1):

In creating your post types `register_post_type`) you need to add with_front as false:

> 'with_front' (bool) Whether the permastruct should be prepended with
> WP_Rewrite::$front. Default true.

so your rewrite could be

```
'rewrite' => array ( 'with_front' => false),
```

or if it's already there with a new slug something like this:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'post_slug', 'with_front' => false),
```